# Typecasting `this` of a base class template to its derived class

Tags: c++, casting

A simplified version of my code looks like so:

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
    void SayHello( T* aDerived )
    {
    }

    void SaySomething()
    {
        SayHello( this ); // This is where the error happens
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base< Derived >
{
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived iDerived;
    iDerived.SaySomething();
}
```

And it won't compile on the `SayHello( this )` line with this error message:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Derived *'
with an rvalue of type 'Base<Derived> *'
```

Now it makes sense for the compiler to complain about this, although it seems to me somewhat stupid it doesn't complain if I remove this line:

```
iDerived.SaySomething();
```

Anyhow, the problem can be solved by doing an explicit typecast, like so:

```
SayHello( (T*)this );
```

The thing is that my actual code ends up with many of these typecasts, and it seems to me reasonable to just include in `Base` something that will allow it to be typecasted automatically to its template class (`T`).

Is it the `operator=` I'm after? Can someone provide a code sample to how this is done? [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275175/using-the-type-conversion-operator) suggests I can do something like:

The cast is always between `this` and `T*`.

```
operator T*()
{
    return (T*)this;
}
```

But the error remains.

Comment: Why do you have a method in your base class that requires being given an argument of the type of a derived class? That seems really weird to me.

Comment: Your use of templates is mystifying to me. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The Base class is really a composite class - it's being given the class to become a composite and decorates it with all composite related interface/implementation. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: What do you mean by "it complies, but doesn't take away the error"?

Comment: Yes, that obviously cannot be the case - corrected.

Comment: And if you guys want to know more why I'm doing this - I can have `composite` referring to itself and do the typecast when clients access the children. But with the above strategy the typecast is done for add/remove of the children, and the iteration is 'native'. Child iteration is far more common that the addition/removal of children, so for performance sake I prefer this strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a helper function that returns `this` downcast to the derived type

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
    void SayHello( T* aDerived )
    {
    }

    void SaySomething()
    {
        SayHello( derived_this() );
    }

private:
    T* derived_this()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this);
    }
```

You might also want a `const` overload:

```
    const T* derived_this() const
    {
        return static_cast<const T*>(this);
    }
```

You *could* add an implicit conversion operator, but I would not recommend it:

```
    operator T*() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
```

Implicit conversions weaken the type system and can be a source of bugs, I think an explicit function such as `derived_this()` is clearer and safer.

Comment: Definitely a better solution than typecasting each instance. I've edited my question to include a reference to the so called 'type conversion operator'.

Comment: Adding the `operator T*() { ... }` doesn't make a difference - same error on the same line.

Comment: That conversion doesn't allow `this` to be converted to `T*`, it allows `*this` to be converted to `T*`, so you'd need to change the callsite to `SayHello( *this )` which is just a bit confusing. You can only add member functions to convert your type, you can't add conversions to pointers. Go with the `derived_this()` solution.

Answer (score 3):

> Although it seems to me somewhat stupid it doesn't complain if I remove this line [...]

No, that's not stupid, it's how templates work. A member function of a class template will never be instantiated if you never call it. Consequently, compilation errors which would be generated while instantiating them won't show up.

> The problem can be solved by doing an explicit typecast, like so [...]

I would prefer a `static_cast<>`:

```
SayHello( static_cast<T*>(this) );
```

The `this` pointer received by your `SaySomething()` function is of type `Base<Derived>`, but you know (by design) that the object pointed to is actually of type `Derived`. Therefore, it is safe to perform a static cast.

> it seems to me reasonable to just include in Base something that will allow it to be typecasted automatically to its template class (T).

There's nothing wrong with casting the pointer many times in this case. That's what the CRTP (the design pattern you are using) forces you to do. If you are bothered by it, just define a `get_this()` function that does the cast for you:

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
    void SayHello( T* aDerived )
    {
    }

    void SaySomething()
    {
        SayHello( get_this() );
    }

private:

    // Version returning a non-const pointer
    T* get_this() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }

    // Version returning a const pointer
    T const* get_this() const { return static_cast<T const*>(this); }

};
```

Comment: What if you have `struct Other : Base<Derived> {};`? Then what?

Comment: @PeterWood: Then you are misusing the base class. That's not how the CRTP is meant to be used

Comment: Yes, but it isn't safe to cast. It's outside of your control as a class designer.

Comment: @PeterWood: As a designer of `Base<>`, you specify your class has to be used that way. If someone else misuses it, that's not your problem.

Comment: @PeterWood, then the `static_cast` will not compile, that's why it's better than `(T*)this`